# Python average by length of a string

Tags: python, excel, import, range, average

I have a data file which has 6 rows of numbers within seven columns of numbers.

Example:

```
5 8 3 21 10 99 3
14 20 100 34 94 2 3
4 2 102 330 101 3 9
9 22 77 721 30 4 9
99 3 4 1 0 55 8 4
8 90 3 1 99 4 101
```

I have the following code and would like to know how to find the average of each line and then each row.

```
def main():

    fileName = input("Enter the name of the data file: ")
    print()
    infile = open(fileName, "r")

#   get data

    sum = 0
    count = 0
    data = infile.read().strip().split()
    for line in len(data):
        sum = sum / len(data)

    print("This is sum: ", sum) 
main()
```

I may only open the file once, I must have everything done with loops, which mean that I must do all of the math for the columns and the rows within looks that reside within the first loop. The output should look something like:

There is a chance that upon turn in, my instructor might set the data file to have more than 7 colums and 6 rows. As such, the code must be able to adapt to this change. The output below was derived from another person who had a similar program to make, but used a fixed file formate. That code would not work in the case that there is a new column added like 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 95, 100... ect or an additional car.

```
                           Speed (MPH)

   Car   :     30     40     50     60     70     80     90  : Average Noise

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    1    :     88     90     94     98    100    110    120  :    100.0
    2    :     75     77     80     86     94    103    113  :     89.7
    3    :     80     83     85     94    111    111    121  :     97.9
    4    :     68     71     76     85     96    122    125  :     91.9
    5    :     77     84     91    102    105    112    119  :     98.6
    6    :     81     85     90     96    102    109    134  :     99.6

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Average :     78.2   81.7   86.0   93.5  101.3  111.2  122.0


 Maximum :     88     90     94    102    111    122    134
```

Anyone have any idea on how to go about doing this? Everything must be flexable to change based upon the imported data file. Just like an excel sheet is.

Comment: This is not how this site works. However, to help you get started I suggest you to look into double dimensional arrays.

Comment: `for line in len(data):`... integer is not iterable.

Comment: Anzel, I was running into that, and every other brick wall when trying to get a single line of code, and discover a way to take the sum of a line, and then divide it by the total number of int's within that line.

To my mind, I need the length, but I don't know how to properly obtain that length and then use it within the code itself.

Personally, I see this as a very unconstructive assignment, as excel would be a superior progrm to use.


To Vineet, thank you, I will look into the double dimensional arrays.

Comment: Ah. I posted the answer using NumPy. And, then read *I must have everything done with loops*.

Comment: Vineet, was this what you meant by a double dimensional array?

myArray = []
 infile = open(fileName, "r")
 lines = infile.readlines()
 for line in lines:
  myArray.append(line.split())

Result:

This is sum:  [['88', '90', '94', '98', '100', '110', '120'], ['75', '77', '80', '86', '94', '103', '113'], ['80', '83', '85', '94', '111', '111',
1'], ['68', '71', '76', '85', '96', '122', '125'], ['77', '84', '91', '102', '105', '112', '119'], ['81', '85', '90', '96', '102', '109', '134']]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd have done the *homework*

First read the csv. But, since the normal way of reading the file would have given us list of strings. So, use `read_lines` function -- which converts list of strings to floats.

```
import csv

def read_lines(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'rU') as data:
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        for row in reader:
            yield [float(cell) for cell in row ]

cars = list(read_lines('car.csv'))
cars

[[88.0, 90.0, 94.0, 98.0, 100.0, 110.0, 120.0],
 [75.0, 77.0, 80.0, 86.0, 94.0, 103.0, 113.0],
 [80.0, 83.0, 85.0, 94.0, 111.0, 111.0, 121.0],
 [68.0, 71.0, 76.0, 85.0, 96.0, 122.0, 125.0],
 [77.0, 84.0, 91.0, 102.0, 105.0, 112.0, 119.0],
 [81.0, 85.0, 90.0, 96.0, 102.0, 109.0, 134.0]]
```

Find the dimension of csv file -- cars and speeds.

```
# Number of speeds
speed_no = float(len(cars[0]))

# Number of cars
cars_no = float(len(cars))
```

Row-wise, find out average value for each row (car) aggregating over different speeds values.

```
# Per car, average value across speed values
for row, car in enumerate(cars):
    print row, sum(car)/speed_no

0 100.0
1 89.7142857143
2 97.8571428571
3 91.8571428571
4 98.5714285714
5 99.5714285714
```

And, we need a function to extract nth column from the array (list of lists)

```
def nth_col(passlist, n):
    return map(lambda x : x[n], passlist)
```

Finally, column-wise, find out average, max value across speed values (i.e per speed)

```
# Per speed, max and average of car values
for num in range(int(speed_no)):
    nth_car = nth_col(cars, num)
    print num, max(nth_car), sum(nth_car)/cars_no

0 88.0 78.1666666667
1 90.0 81.6666666667
2 94.0 86.0
3 102.0 93.5
4 111.0 101.333333333
5 122.0 111.166666667
6 134.0 122.0
```

However, I'd preferred NumPy/Pandas version over loops.

**Numpy Version**

You could use [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html)

```
In [30]: import numpy as np
In [37]: np_arr = np.genfromtxt('car.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
In [39]: np_arr
Out[39]:
array([[  88.,   90.,   94.,   98.,  100.,  110.,  120.],
       [  75.,   77.,   80.,   86.,   94.,  103.,  113.],
       [  80.,   83.,   85.,   94.,  111.,  111.,  121.],
       [  68.,   71.,   76.,   85.,   96.,  122.,  125.],
       [  77.,   84.,   91.,  102.,  105.,  112.,  119.],
       [  81.,   85.,   90.,   96.,  102.,  109.,  134.]])
```

column-wise mean

```
In [41]: np_arr.mean(axis=0)
Out[41]:
array([  78.16666667,   81.66666667,   86.        ,   93.5       ,
        101.33333333,  111.16666667,  122.        ])
```

row-wise mean

```
In [42]: np_arr.mean(axis=1)
Out[42]:
array([ 100.        ,   89.71428571,   97.85714286,   91.85714286,
         98.57142857,   99.57142857])
```

column-wise max

```
In [43]: np_arr.max(axis=0)
Out[43]:
array([  88.,   90.,   94.,  102.,  111.,  122.,  134.])
```

I'll leave the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) version for you to try out.

Comment: And, there you have the *I must have everything done with loops* version along with vectorized NumPy version.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

You need the range() function around your len(data) to iterate.

If your wanting an average, the equation you have: `sum = sum / len(data)` would not find the average. You must sum over the values somewhere. Presently your taking 0 / some value = 0. If you use `sum += sum + data[line] / len(data)` that would work. Alternatively, you can sum over the values in your loop and then divide by the number of entries. These two methods will be equivalent. In the former your just adding on each successive value to the sum while doing the division right then. In terms of following the code though, it would likely be clearer if you do the latter, showing each step separately.

Regarding the formatting: I don't want to give everything away for this as this seems to be the bulk of your homework assignment, but will provide some tips.
You should keep track of the number of entries in each line, and store the maximum value of entries in some variable. That way when you go to format your table, you can call this variable to dictate how many columns you need to make. In terms of adjusting for how many rows, use a for loop where each iteration of the loop makes one of the lines. Before starting this for loop have it make the header (your ----- line and everything above it) and then after the for loop have it make the footer (your ----- line and everything below it).

For your Maximum line at the bottom, I would recommend creating a dict to store the maximum values for each column as you go through each line. Use the column value as your key and some logic to test if the stored value associated with the key is larger than the current stored value, and if so, replace it.

Lastly, you should remember to close your file. You opened it at the beginning, but did not close it.

Hopefully this helps.